# How to limit the workload of an OpenGL application?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a very basic OpenGL application that just draws a triangle from data stored in a buffer. Yet after running a few minutes the computer runs very hot, even more than when running a full game.

How do I limit the workload that the application generates?
Is there another method than `sleep`ing in the main loop?

Comment: Since you are using GLFW, you can also limit the refresh rate with `glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_REFRESH_RATE, <rate>)`. This only works in fullscreen mode though. Making sure v-sync is enabled should be enough, but it's useful if you want it even lower (eg. 30 FPS).

Answer (score 2):

First you should check that V-Sync is enabled: Time the duration between main loop iterations to obtain the frequency by which your main loop and thereby redraw function are executed. Unless you're performing a system benchmark V-Sync should be enabled and a main loop calling a display function in the end should run at maximum the display refresh frequency.

If V-Sync is not enabled, i.e. you get a extremely high framerate (larger than 120Hz), you should first enable V-Sync in your graphics driver.

If your program is still consuming too much CPU time, make sure you're not polling, but waiting for events in your main loop. And as a last measure on Windows systems you should add a `Sleep(1);` after the call to `…SwapBuffers` (note the capital `S`) which reliably yields CPU time to the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using glut you can use the `glutMainLoop()` which should take care of that for you.

But do not forget to register the update and render methods as well as the handle-methods for keyboard and mouse

```
  glutDisplayFunc(updateGL);
  glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
  glutIdleFunc(idle);
  glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardEvent);
  glutMouseFunc(mouseEvent);
  glutMotionFunc(mouseMoveEvent);
  glutCloseFunc(close);
```

The parameters are the names of the functions